# Looping around a radio list to click on each list item

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I'm trying to loop around a radio list and click on each list item in turn.  Here is the code from the page:

```
<div><input type="radio" name="voiceSpeed" class="rtSlow"><span i18n-content="​&quot;voiceSpeedSlow&quot;">&nbsp;​Slow</span><br><input type="radio" name="voiceSpeed" value="true" checked=""><span i18n-content="​&quot;voiceSpeedMedium&quot;" class="rtMedium">&nbsp;Medium​</span><br><input type="radio" name="voiceSpeed" class="rtFast"><span i18n-content="​&quot;voiceSpeedFast&quot;">&nbsp;Fast​</span><br></div>
```

This is what I have come up with (it works ok but that's the issue.  It's just ok.  I just wanted some advice / ideas on how to simplify it)

I'm using c#

```
IwebElement SlowRadionButton = driver.FindElement(By.ClassName("rtSlow"));
IwebElement MediumRadionButton = driver.FindElement(By.ClassName("rtMedium"));
IwebElement FastRadionButton = driver.FindElement(By.ClassName("rtFast"));

Object[] SpeedRadioButtons = new Object[] { SlowRadioButton. MediumRadioButton, FastRadionButton }

for (int 1 = 0; 1 < SpeedRadioButtons.Count(); i++)
{
if (i == 0)
SlowRadioButton.Click();
}
else if (i == 1)
{
MediumRadionButton.Click();
}
else if (i == 2)
{
FastRadionButton.Click();
}
```

Thanks for much for any help.  Much appreciated

Comment: This might be better suited for Code Review. StackOverflow is meant for solving problems with your code, not refactoring.

Comment: That being said, you could try using a foreach loop to click each button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Absolutely nothing to do with Selenium. This is just a pure programming logic issue, which is "how do I iterate through a list".

Use a `foreach` loop:

```
IWebElement SlowRadionButton = driver.FindElement(By.ClassName("rtSlow"));
IWebElement MediumRadionButton = driver.FindElement(By.ClassName("rtMedium"));
IWebElement FastRadionButton = driver.FindElement(By.ClassName("rtFast"));

var speedRadioButtons = new[] { SlowRadioButton. MediumRadioButton, FastRadionButton }

foreach (IWebElement speedRadioButton in speedRadioButtons)
{
    speedRadioButton.Click();
}
```

(pseudo-code, not compiled it)